# Not rename database in query on replication on same server

Tags: mysql, database-replication

MYSQL 5.1.73 
I use replication on the same server
my.cfg

```
server-id=1
report-host=master-is-slave-host
log-bin=myserver-binlog
relay-log=myserver-relaylog
replicate-same-server-id=1
binlog-do-db=pal_main
replicate-rewrite-db=pal_main->pal_test
replicate-do-db=pal_test
expire_logs_days = 5
```

all works fine, but it has error on queries with databes name in it

```
INSERT INTO `pal_main`.`api_log` (`ID`, ...) VALUES (NULL, ...)'
```

result:

> Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'' on
>   query. Default database: 'pal_test'. Query: 'INSERT INTO
>   'pal_main'.'api_log' ('ID', ...) VALUES (NULL, ...)'

On query:

```
INSERT INTO `api_log` (`ID`, ...) VALUES (NULL, ...)'
```

no problems on slave

it looks like it not replace database name in query and getting error trying insert in master

Comment: what do you mean, "replace database name"? Normally slaves are read-only, and you insert on masters. if you're getting these duplicate key violations, you didn't set up replication correctly, e.g. master-master, instead of master-slave.

Comment: I haven't used replication a whole lot, even though I have years of experience writing queries for MySQL databases; I have to wonder, what it the benefit of replicating on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

`binlog-do-db` will only replicate statements when the *current* database is the specified database if `binlog_format` is set to `STATEMENT`.  The same issue may or may not occur when set to `MIXED`.

If you `USE pal_main;` first, the query would replicate.  Otherwise, it doesn't.

For what you are doing, you need `binlog_format=ROW` for consistent behavior.  This should remove the need to check the current database when MySQL is deciding whether to write to the Binlog.

You are operating with a delicate configuration.